# Failed to resolve: com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, swipe

I have the following problem: in android studio I want to load the library 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1' which I took from here: https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout
But android studio does not give me permission and gives me an error. Who knows how to solve this?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UaQU.png)]

Code gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.justwork'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.justwork"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'

}
```

I looked at this library in the dialog box and saw that it was impossible to select a version for it. From which I conclude that for some reason android studio does not give me access to this resource.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdyNQ.png)]

Comment: The library seems abandoned, and is not published on Maven Central. You can try and use JitPack https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

This lib is on jcenter but jcenter is shut down.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add jcenter() in settings.gradle(project Settings)